# How do I prepare data for Rouder & Morey (2012) default prior?

Tags: bayesian, prior, bayes-factors

I am going to run an analysis using the default prior outlined by [Rouder and Morey (2012)](http://pcl.missouri.edu/sites/default/files/Rouder.Morey_.MBR_.2012.pdf); however, I am unclear how exactly to prepare the data.

As a quick overview, I have a continuous DV and a dichotomous predictor.

The section on reparameterization appears the bottom of page 883.

"The first property, that the Bayes factor should be invariant to the units of measurement, is met by reparameterizing the model in terms of a standardized effect measure. Model M1 may be rewritten as [Formula 4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iiFZb.jpg) where Sx is the (population) standard deviation of x and BETA is the standardized
effect given by [Formula 5](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7j3r2.jpg). It is straightforward to show that Equations (2) and (4) are reparameterizations of the same model. The parameter BETA describes how much a change in standard deviation units of x affects a change in standard deviation units of y... This standardization should not be confused with the more conventional standardization where data and covariates are transformed so that the slope is constrained to be between  1 and 1 (Kutner, Nachtsheim, Neter, & Li, 2004)." (pp. 883-884, Rouder & Morey, 2012)

I'm left a bit unclear as exactly how to how exactly to prepare my data for this prior. Am I right to interpret this as me having to center my predictor and then divide it by its standard deviation (i.e., z score it)? I'm also unclear if this changes when the predictor is a dichotomous, rather than continuous, variable?